# Calculating an easy iterated integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following integral:

> $$ \int_{0}^{t}dt_{1}^{'} \int_{0}^{t_1}dt_{2}^{'} \; \sin \; [k(t_1^{'} - t_2^{'})]. $$

The correct answer is:

> $$  \frac{\sin(kt) - kt}{k^2}.      $$

My reasoning, however, gives me the following result:

The first inetgral gives me the result:

> $$  \int_{0}^{t_1} dt_{2}^{'} \; \sin \; [k(t_1^{'} - t_2^{'})] = \frac{- \cos \; [k(t_1^{'} - t_2^{'})] }{-k} \mid_{0}^{t_1} = \frac{\cos \; [k(t_1^{'} - t_1)]}{k} - \frac{\cos \; (kt_1^{'})}{k}.                     $$

The second integral gives the result:

> $$  \int_{0}^{t} dt_{1}^{'} \; \frac{\cos \; [k(t_1^{'} - t_1)]}{k} - \frac{\cos \; (kt_1^{'})}{k} = \frac{\sin \; [k(t - t_1)]}{k^2}  - \frac{\sin \; [k(- t_1)]}{k^2}  - \frac{\sin(kt)}{k^2}.              $$

My final answer is:

> $$ \frac{\sin \; [k(t - t_1)]}{k^2}  + \frac{\sin \; [kt_1]}{k^2}  - \frac{\sin(kt)}{k^2}.  $$

But this clearly doesn't match with the correct answer, as given in the resource from where I got the integral.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps the upper limit of integration on the inner definite integral should be $t_1'$ and not $t_1$?

Comment: Shouldn't the argument be difference in sign, for example? I'm integrating over $t_{1}^{'}$; how could I use the dummy/variable of integration as the upper limit as well. Isn't it supposed to be a particular realization of the variable of integration: $t_1 = t_{1}^{'}$ is one possible value of $t_{1}^{'}$.

Comment: The upper limit can be any function of variables that you have not yet integrated. So in your example, the upper limit of the inner integral can be a function of $t_1'$, which might be a constant, but doesn't have to be.

What is "right" here depends entirely on the context. I suggest changing the upper limit to $t_1'$ and see if you get what you stated as the "correct" answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\int_{0}^{t}\dd t_{1}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}\dd t_{2}
\sin\pars{k\bracks{t_{1} - t_{2}}}} =
\Im\int_{0}^{t}\exp\pars{\ic k t_{1}}\int_{0}^{t_{1}}
\exp\pars{-\ic kt_{2}}\,\dd t_{2}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[3mm] = &\
\Im\int_{0}^{t}\exp\pars{\ic kt_{1}}\,
{\exp\pars{-\ic kt_{1}} - 1 \over -\ic k}\,\dd t_{1} =
{1 \over k}\,\Re\int_{0}^{t}\bracks{1 - \exp\pars{\ic kt_{1}}}\,\dd t_{1}
\\[3mm] = &\
{1 \over k}\,\Re\bracks{t - {\exp\pars{\ic k t} - 1 \over \ic k}} =
{1 \over k}\,\Re\bracks{t - {-\ic\cos\pars{kt} + \sin\pars{kt} + \ic \over k}} =
\color{#f00}{{kt - \sin\pars{kt} \over k^{2}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

As I found, if you replace $t'_1$ and $t'_2$ with $t_1$ and $t_2$, respectively, and employ your method, then you will obtain the correct answer. Otherwise, as you have $t_1$ as upper limit of interior integral, it would be appeared in the final answer anyway (as it is seen in your answer), and so you cannot get the correct answer (the desired answer given by you).